# GDAL warp not transforming raster properly

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdalwarp

I have a raster Tiff image which I want to reproject from EPSG:27700 TO EPSG:3857 in GDAL.

Using `gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:27700 -t_srs EPSG:3857 C:/test/input.tif C:/test/output.tif` I have noticed that the transformation is incorrect as it misaligns the raster.

The correct transformation I am looking for is that below, found in QGIS

[image]

Using the pipeline from QGIS I have tried `gdalwarp -ct "+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +step +proj=push +v_3 +step +proj=cart +ellps=airy +step +proj=helmert +x=446.448 +y=-125.157 +z=542.06 +rx=0.15 +ry=0.247 +rz=0.842 +s=-20.489 +convention=position_vector +step +inv +proj=cart +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=pop +v_ +step +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84" C:/test/input.tif C:/test/output.tif`

but this gives me an output raster placed off the coast of Africa.
I'd rather not use `-ct` but instead `-s_srs` and `-t_srs` but cant work them out from the pipeline

What am I doing wrong, or how do I set it to be the transformation required?

Comment: possibly related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76411/issues-using-geographic-and-projected-coordinate-systems-qgis-2-0

Comment: I think you must use both the -ct pipeline to define your preferred transformation and the -t_srs parameter to set the spatial reference system for output file.